# Terminal Command - Finding and counting files using (kMDItemContentCreationDate)

Tags: macos, search, terminal, find, metadata

While performing some recent research, I captured a few thousand image and video files.

To report my data, I need to search specific directories and count all files by their actual creation date and output the results to csv so I can filter and manipulate the data further.

My challenge is knowing the syntax required to count files using a metadata property such as `kMDItemContentCreationDate`.

I’d like the final report format to resemble this structure (without the -- ):

```
 DD/MM/YYY -- TYPE -- COUNT<br>
 01/01/2017 -- .JPG -- 12<br>
 02/01/2017 -- .JPG -- 19<br>
 03/01/2017 -- .JPG -- 11<br>
 04/01/2017 -- .JPG -- 27<br>
```

I have tried to find the string I need, but so far with no success and it has been driving me crazy trying in the process.

Are you able to please guide as what is necessary to achieve my desired outcome?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately your question boils down to "somebody please please help me with this". But we do not regard such requests as *questions* in the scope of this site. Please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) carefully to understand why that is. Then consider to either delete this question and putting up a new, more precise question within the scope of this community. Alternatively, you could rework and improve this question. Thanks!

Comment: See if you can get the date for a single file and show your code https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/mdls.1.html Then look at the `find` command and its `-exec` feature to try and exec the single command for each file...

Answer (score 0):

If you run this command in the Terminal, you can get the dates of all the `JPG` files:

```
mdls -name kMDItemContentCreationDate *jpg
```

The output will look something like this:

```
kMDItemContentCreationDate = 2017-08-08 08:50:54 +0000
kMDItemContentCreationDate = 2017-08-19 06:59:09 +0000
kMDItemContentCreationDate = 2017-08-04 06:42:50 +0000
kMDItemContentCreationDate = 2017-02-05 14:46:41 +0000
kMDItemContentCreationDate = 2013-03-09 08:59:50 +0000
kMDItemContentCreationDate = 2017-08-04 06:52:36 +0000
kMDItemContentCreationDate = 2017-08-08 08:55:01 +0000
kMDItemContentCreationDate = 2017-08-08 08:55:37 +0000
kMDItemContentCreationDate = 2017-08-08 08:56:39 +0000
kMDItemContentCreationDate = 2017-08-04 06:44:02 +0000
kMDItemContentCreationDate = 2017-08-08 08:57:28 +0000
```

If you add some `awk`, you can extract just the date in the third field:

```
mdls -name kMDItemContentCreationDate *jpg | awk '{print $3}'
```

The output will then look like this:

```
2017-08-08
2017-08-19
2017-08-04
2017-02-05
2013-03-09
2017-08-04
2017-08-08
2017-08-08
2017-08-08
2017-08-04
2017-08-08
```

If you pass that into `sort` and `uniq` you can get a count of how often each line repeats:

```
mdls -name kMDItemContentCreationDate *jpg | awk '{print $3}'| sort -n | uniq -c
1 2013-03-09
1 2017-02-05
3 2017-08-04
5 2017-08-08
1 2017-08-19
```

If you repeat that for the extensions `jpg` and `mov` and put it in a script called `go` in your HOME directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob nocaseglob
for ext in jpg mov; do
   echo Checking extension $ext ...
   mdls -name kMDItemContentCreationDate *$ext | awk '{print $3}' | sort -n | uniq -c
done
```

You can then make it executable (just do this once):

```
chmod +x $HOME/go
```

Then you can change directory to anywhere you like and run it:

```
cd Somewhere/with/a/bunch/of/pictures/and/movies
$HOME/go
```

**Sample Output**

```
Checking extension jpg ...
   1 2013-03-09
   1 2017-02-05
   3 2017-08-04
   5 2017-08-08
   1 2017-08-19
Checking extension mov ...
   2 2017-08-20
```

---

If you are really picky and want out more or less exactly as you asked, change the script to:

```
#!/bin/bash
pwd
shopt -s nullglob nocaseglob
for ext in jpg mov; do
   echo Checking extension $ext ...
   mdls -name kMDItemContentCreationDate *$ext | awk '{print $3}' | sort -n | uniq -c | awk -v ext=$ext '{print $2,ext,$1}'
done
```

**Sample Output**

```
/Users/mark/tmp
Checking extension jpg ...
2013-03-09 jpg 1
2017-02-05 jpg 1
2017-08-04 jpg 3
2017-08-08 jpg 5
2017-08-19 jpg 1
Checking extension mov ...
2017-08-20 mov 2
```